# Adding to map and set method

Tags: java, methods

Im new to Java so please forgive my ignorance,I am trying my best to not ask a stupid question.

I need to write a method that takes two arguments, one being the key for my map (String) the other is the value (my map has values that are sets of a user defined object called Object that has three string values itself).

so far I have:

```
public void addMapObject(String aKey, Object anObject)//what would the anObject arguement look like?
```

{
      Set objects = new HashSet<>();
      objects.add(new Object("","",""); //how do I initialize these values?
      MyMap.put(aKey, objects);
   }

Apologies if this is not clear I will be happy to clarify if needed.

Thank you very much for the help it has clicked now.

Comment: This is not clear.  Why can't you just do `myMap.put(aKey, anObject)`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth So my method argument would look something like addMapObject("Key1", what do I put here to initialise the object state?)

Comment: I don't know - what do you mean by "the object state"?  It's really unclear what type of objects you're talking about here.

Comment: This question is really unclear. You declared a class `Object`? If you did, you should really choose another name for the class, since `java.lang.Object` is already a well known class in Java. Where is the declaration of your class `Object`? Also, what is `addMapObject` supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to create an object, like so:

```
pubic class MyObject{
  private String something;
  private Integer something2;
  private Double something3;
  //or whatever data types you want

  //Generate getters and setters
}
```

So you now have an object that holds something.

After that, you have to initialize a map to hold your object so in your method above or as a global "field" in that same class you need to:

```
Map<String,MyObject> map = new HashMap<String,MyObject>();
```

Your method signature should then include MyObject instead of Object and you can use:

```
map.put(aKey, anObject)
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear guys, I have got up to this point! I explained it badly I apologise. Now from here how do I actually put an object into the map?

Comment: As Oliver Charlesworth said: map.put(aKey,anObject).  If you want to initialize an object while putting it in the map use: map.put(aKey, new MyObject());

Answer (score -1):

Class `Object` is java defined class and is part of `java.lang` package. Each class is sub class of this class. I feel you should create a separate class. 
You can create a class like below

```
public class Bean{
    String valueOne;
    String valueTwo;
    String valueThree;
    public Bean(String valueOne, String valueTwo, String valueThree) {
        super();
        this.valueOne = valueOne;
        this.valueTwo = valueTwo;
        this.valueThree = valueThree;
    }

}
```

You need to change the signature of the method

```
public void addMapObject(String aKey, Bean anObject) {
    Set<Object> objects = new HashSet<>();
    objects.add(anObject);
    MyMap.put(aKey, objects);
}
```

And then you asked as how to initialize, you would do it in the caller method as below

```
public void theCallerMethod(){
    addMapObject("YourKey", new Bean("YourActualvalueOne","YourActualvalueTwo","YourActualvalueThree"));
}
```

But once you do this you should also take care of the `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods as you need to add the objects of your class in an HashSet. These methods are defined in base class `Object.java`. Details as why you need to do this, I suggest you to study this and can refer below link 
[Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)

Your class bean would finally look like below

```
public static class Bean {
    String valueOne;
    String valueTwo;
    String valueThree;

    public Bean(String valueOne, String valueTwo, String valueThree) {
        super();
        this.valueOne = valueOne;
        this.valueTwo = valueTwo;
        this.valueThree = valueThree;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((valueOne == null) ? 0 : valueOne.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((valueThree == null) ? 0 : valueThree.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((valueTwo == null) ? 0 : valueTwo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Bean other = (Bean) obj;
        if (valueOne == null) {
            if (other.valueOne != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!valueOne.equals(other.valueOne))
            return false;
        if (valueThree == null) {
            if (other.valueThree != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!valueThree.equals(other.valueThree))
            return false;
        if (valueTwo == null) {
            if (other.valueTwo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!valueTwo.equals(other.valueTwo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this code even do?  What is the purpose of `anObject`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Thanks for correcting me. I edited my answer. Down vote accepted sir, it was my mistake.

Comment: What would the method caller look like if it was a set of bean objects?

Comment: @WillD, I have included it in mu answer. See the method theCallerMethod()

Comment: in case it was Set and not the Map then simply the call would be addMapObject( new Bean("YourActualvalueOne","YourActualvalueTwo","YourActualvalueThree"));
addMapObject() method would accept the Set<Bean> as parameter.

Comment: @WillD did your concern got resolved or you still need help ?

Comment: @nits.kk  think that is everything, thank you very much for the help.